# How to resize a image dynamically on the run using Codeigniter/PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is an Foursquare image url I am sharing:-

https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/width960/59805036_Qt3WZYJ5z3_LPh8tpG4wtqJSrVokkKioxYebWogfOjo.jpg

It shows the original image. Now, if I use the following image link,

https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/200x1600/59805036_Qt3WZYJ5z3_LPh8tpG4wtqJSrVokkKioxYebWogfOjo.jpg

The image automatically gets resized based on the dimension 200x1600. Give any dimension and the image gets resized automatically, which proves that there is  no dimension predefined.

When the above link in placed in the url, the image gets resized automatically. How can this be managed dynamically on the run suing Codeigniter or PHP?

I have absolutely no idea about this.

Comment: if you can manage that statically - you can do this in a dynamic way too - just use the passed arguments (in your case width960 and 200x1600)

Comment: You didn't understand my question, do you?

Comment: do you want to bait me ? i think i perfectly understand what you mean... there are predefined sets which you can define and the image gets resized based on that information e.g. https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/height400/59805036_Qt3WZYJ5z3_LPh8tpG4wtqJSrVokkKioxYebWogfOjo.jpg works perfectly on the other hand if you use anything which isn't defined like https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/heig1ht400/59805036_Qt3WZYJ5z3_LPh8tpG4wtqJSrVokkKioxYebWogfOjo.jpg you won't get anything - imho this is a pretty easy task u r asking here...

Comment: I want to build a system like this in Codeigniter or custom PHP. I was wondering if there is any tutotial or library that does it. Since I was unable to find such, I asked here. I just don't want to resize the image by changing the dimension in the given link, I want to build a system like that. And yes, give irregular dimension like 353x417. You will get exact size. So there is nothing predefined.

Comment: ofc its predefined - not the dimension but the set is predefined - you can use keywords like width, height and such thing and the dimensions are dynamic ... and if you use the image manipulation library you should get what you want pretty easily, take a closer look here ...(https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html?highlight=image), the original image has to fit - you cant use an image with 300x200 and expect that a 2000px height value would gv a suitable result

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with CI. read the documentation for [image manipulation class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html).

you will need to create a controller to handle that:

```
<?php

class Image extends CI_Controller
{

    public function resize($filename, $width, $height){

        // path to image in your project
        $image_path = 'uploads/img/'.$filename;

        // if image doesn't exist show 404 error
        if(!file_exists($image_path))
            show_404();

        // Load image library
        $this->load->library('image_lib');


        // configure image library
        $config = array(
            'image_library' => 'gd2',
            'source_image' => $image_path,
            'dynamic_output' => true,
            'width' => $width,
            'height' => $height,
        );

        // load configuration
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        // resize
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }

}
```

Now open your browser and try it: localhost/project_folder/image/resize/example.jpg/500/500

to make the URL look like the one in the question, you can add route to routes configuration file.